# Accessing device accelerometer in web javascript on a local file on smartphone

Tags: javascript, html, accelerometer, webapi, devicemotion

I'm wondering why my smartphone isn't able to access the accelerometer from javascript. I loaded the file onto the smartphone's (android) files, but no motion data is being read.

It works fine on my tablet, but the same script doesn't work on my android phone. I'm using the function:

```
ondevicemotion = function(e) {

}
```

It does nothing on the android phone. Anybody know why this is?

I tried loading the file directly onto the android smartphone. I expected the script to work the same that it does on my tablet, but no device motion data is read. I also tried on an iphone and it did not work.